# How to add `unique` constraint to already existing index by migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How can I add `unique: true` constraint to already existing index in Rails database?

I tried to migrate by

```
  def change
    add_index :editabilities, [:user_id, :list_id], unique: true
  end
```

but migration fails with a error like this.

> Index name 'index_editabilities_on_user_id_and_list_id' on table
>   'editabilities' already exists

I'm using rails4 and postgresql.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Remove the old index and add it again with the new constraint:

```
def change
  remove_index :editabilities, [:user_id, :list_id]
  add_index :editabilities, [:user_id, :list_id], unique: true
end
```

Comment: I had to do this in two migrations in order for `schema.rb` to be updated.

Comment: `schema.rb` was updated fine for me on Rails 4.2.0. Possibly a bug that's now been resolved? Or maybe it's database dependent; I'm using Postgres.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a foreign key constraint which prevents you from removing the index. In that case you can 
remove the foreign key, then remove the index and then add the new index again. 

```ruby
...
  remove_foreign_key :editabilities, column: :user_id
  remove_index :editabilities, :user_id
  add_index :editabilities, :user_id, unique: true
end
```

If you rely on the index in your production database you might want to add a new modified index first with a different name, so you have two indices. Then you can remove the old index and afterwards rename the new index.

Comment: @Baldrick's solution worked fine for me, even with a foreign key on the column!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is not exactly safe for huge tables. What might happen is:

1. Index is removed successfully
2. Adding a new index takes forever and/or fails

In this situation you end up having no index at all. And if you have a fair amount of traffic and loads of queries that used to use the index you might run into big trouble.

For large tables I suggest:

1. De-dupe records having the same value on the indexed column.
2. Add a unique index with a different name than the non-unique one (you'll temporarily have two indexes on the same column, with different names):

```rb
class AddUniqueUuidIndexToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def up
    add_index :items, :uuid, name: index_name, unique: true
  end

  def down
    remove_index :items, column: :uuid, name: index_name
  end

  private

  def index_name
    'unique_index_items_on_uuid'
  end
end
```

3. Remove the old, non-unique index (cleanup step):

```rb
class RemoveNonUniqueIndexFromItemsUuid < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def up
    remove_index :items, column: :uuid, name: index_name
  end

  def down
    add_index :items, :uuid, name: index_name
  end

  private

  # old index name, check db/schema.rb to find the actual name
  def index_name
    'index_items_on_uuid'
  end
end
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `add_index` *before* `remove_index` in a single migration instead of separating the into two migrations?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the existing index then you may need to do more than that:

1. Delete duplicated data.
2. Add uniqueness index.

This is the safest way to add uniqueness constraints into existing indexes with large data in production.

```
class AddStoreIdUniquenessIndexToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    delete_duplicated_records

    rename_index :orders, :index_orders_on_store_id, :non_uniqueness_index_orders_on_store_id
    add_index :orders, :store_id, unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
    remove_index :orders, name: :non_uniqueness_index_orders_on_store_id, column: :store_id
  end

  def down
    remove_index :orders, name: :index_orders_on_store_id, column: :store_id
    add_index :orders, :store_id, name: :index_orders_on_store_id
  end

  private

  def delete_duplicated_records
    dup_store_ids = Order.group(:store_id).having('COUNT(*) > 1').pluck(:store_id)
    dup_store_ids.each_slice(400) do |store_ids|
      not_remove_order_ids = Order.where(store_id: store_ids).group(:store_id).having('COUNT(*) > 1').pluck('MIN(id)')
      Order.where(store_id: store_ids).where.not(id: not_remove_order_ids).destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```

Note:

> As you see, I rename the index `index_orders_on_store_id` before
> deleting it. It's for performance purposes. This means if the
> migration fails while adding the new index, and we have to re-run the
> migration, we’re now executing the query without an index on the
> retail_orders column.
>
> If you’re doing a big ol’ query against a few hundred thousand rows of
> data, with the index, it’ll take a few seconds. Without the index, it
> could take… many minutes.